# How to Create Drop-Down links in Top Link Bar in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am trying to create a drop-down menu in the top link bar in SharePoint 2010. I would like to select an item on the top link bar and have that item not be a URL to another page but instead trigger a drop-down menu with links to other pages.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the multilevel dropdown using jQuery or JavaScript